# Chrome extension content script re-injection after upgrade or install

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, content-script

After the Chrome extension I'm working on is installed, or upgraded, the content scripts (specified in the manifest) are not re-injected so a page refresh is required to make the extension work. Is there a way to force the scripts to be injected again?

I believe I could inject them again programmatically by removing them from the manifest and then handling which pages to inject in the background page, but this is not a good solution.

I don't want to automatically refresh the user's tabs because that could lose some of their data. Safari automatically refreshes all pages when you install or upgrade an extension.

Comment: Looks like Safari 7 (at least) no longer automatically refreshes the page when an extension is installed

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There's a way to allow a content script heavy extension to continue functioning after an upgrade, and to make it work immediately upon installation.

## Install/upgrade

The install method is to simply iterate through all tabs in all windows, and inject some scripts programmatically into tabs with matching URLs.

#### ManifestV3

manifest.json:

```json
"background": {"service_worker": "background.js"},
"permissions": ["scripting"],
"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
```

These host_permissions should be the same as the content script's `matches`.

background.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {
  for (const cs of chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts) {
    for (const tab of await chrome.tabs.query({url: cs.matches})) {
      if (tab.url.match(/(chrome|chrome-extension):\/\//gi)) {
        continue;
      }
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        files: cs.js,
        target: {tabId: tab.id, allFrames: cs.all_frames},
        injectImmediately: cs.run_at === 'document_start',
        // world: cs.world, // uncomment if you use it in manifest.json in Chrome 111+
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This is a simplified example that doesn't handle frames. You can use [getAllFrames](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/#method-getAllFrames) API and match the URLs yourself, see the documentation for [matching patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

##### Caveats & Notes

- If you still have old tabs open you may get an error: `Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.` You will need to refresh those tabs so that they now have the new extension code that will auto-reload them.
- You may now get a new error or still get `Error: Extension context invalidated.` If you are still receiving this you will need to remove any old event handlers on the page for the content script see: [Chrome Extension: How to remove orphaned script after Chrome extension update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468219/chrome-extension-how-to-remove-orphaned-script-after-chrome-extension-update)

#### ManifestV2

Obviously, you have to do it in a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) script declared in manifest.json:

```js
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
```

background.js:

```js
// Add a `manifest` property to the `chrome` object.
chrome.manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();

var injectIntoTab = function (tab) {
    // You could iterate through the content scripts here
    var scripts = chrome.manifest.content_scripts[0].js;
    var i = 0, s = scripts.length;
    for( ; i < s; i++ ) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            file: scripts[i]
        });
    }
}

// Get all windows
chrome.windows.getAll({
    populate: true
}, function (windows) {
    var i = 0, w = windows.length, currentWindow;
    for( ; i < w; i++ ) {
        currentWindow = windows[i];
        var j = 0, t = currentWindow.tabs.length, currentTab;
        for( ; j < t; j++ ) {
            currentTab = currentWindow.tabs[j];
            // Skip chrome:// and https:// pages
            if( ! currentTab.url.match(/(chrome|https):\/\//gi) ) {
                injectIntoTab(currentTab);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

##### Historical trivia

In ancient Chrome 26 and earlier content scripts could restore connection to the background script. It was fixed http://crbug.com/168263 in 2013. You can see an example of this trick in the earlier revisions of this answer.

Comment: in chrome 46 you need to use `chrome.runtime.getManifest()` rather than `chrome.manifest`.

Comment: To execute chrome.tabs.executeScript you have to add permissions "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" to your manifest.json

Comment: What happens say user is watching a video by execution of content script of v1.0 in a web page and Google Chrome upgrades to v.2.0? Does v1.0 execution halt? Or as with this answer, including new and old content scripts at the same time for the tab should not create issue?

Comment: Hi, can you tell me where do you do the getAll and InjectIntoTab? Since in manifest.json I have 'background.js' and content_scripts.js file, but I can't figure out what is executed first time on install. Thanks, Mirko

Comment: I tried the upgrade code and it works on Firefox but not Opera, and presumably not on Chrome.

Comment: "http://*/*" permission is not required if you only inject content scripts on specific pages. Make sure to just add your domain as permission in order to inject on your own pages only. Using "http://*/*" actually triggers a manual review by google which might take a while.

Comment: but connectToExtension and reconnectToExtension are running in infinite loop. What can be wrong? onDisconnect shoudn't listening only when extension is upgraded / reloaded?

Comment: Is this gonna work for more than one file in content script? The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#injected-code) says "Note: Currently, a maximum of a single file is supported.". Also, is it OK to re-inject it also on browser update? Or should one check the `runtime.onInstalled` "reason" parameter and restrict it to update/install?

Comment: This answer is not going to work if the extension is disabled and then enabled

Comment: @traxium do you know a good way to determine "enabled" state?

Comment: Figured that best way is to run it both within the onInstalled listener and outside, so that whenever the background script is loaded, we re-inject and make sure connection with all contentscripts exists. Perhaps there's also a way to check for connection and trigger it only when it's not available.. but I took the safe way

Comment: @OwenFar I was trying to say that `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` wrapper in the mv3 answer needs to be removed if you also want to re-inject content scripts on the extension disabling/enabling

Comment: why the `v3` solution does not work on `v2`? it looks a fine code to run on `v2` manifest.

Comment: I noticed in the v2 code it handles `chrome://` pages, but in the v3 code it does not. I'm currently getting errors around:  `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL` and `Cannot access a chrome-extension:// URL of different extension`, but I'm not certain which is causing: `Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.` I do have the `"<all_urls>"` on both `host_permissions` & `content_scripts`. I also enabled the `world` option.

Comment:  After adding a check to skip the chrome pages via: `if (tab.url.match(/(chrome|chrome-extension):\/\//gi)) continue;` I was still getting the error: `Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.`. I was able to resolve this by refreshing the tabs that were causing this. You could also likely restart your browser to resolve this. Those tabs likely still had the old content script that did not yet have the code to handle the `onInstalled` event listener. I'm going to add this to the answer 

Comment: Here's the other half of this that I ran into after fixing this issue. Now that the new script hander is in place, we need to remove the old event handler, otherwise it will try to interact with the old `chrome.runtime` that no longer exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468219/chrome-extension-how-to-remove-orphaned-script-after-chrom-extension-update/57471345#57471345

Answer (score 31):

The only way to force a content script to be injected *without refreshing the page* is via programatic injection.

You can get all tabs and inject code into them using the chrome tabs API.
For example you can store a manifest version in local storage and every time check if the manifest version is old one (in background page), if so you can get all active tabs and inject your code programmatically, or any other solution that will make you sure that the extension is updated.

Get all tabs using:
[chrome.tabs.query](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html)

and inject your code into all pages
`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "content_script.js"});`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use this method – programmatic injection requires a lot more code and increases complexity.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the only way to do it. I implemented a similar thing, using both the manifest injection and programatic injection so all tabs that are open when the background script is first loaded are injected, and all new tabs are handled by the normal manifest injection. The thing you should watch out for, however, is anything you leave behind in the DOM or page context for e.g. reloading or upgrading, so you should have a function that undoes everything you've done, but also need to get the new context to talk to the old one.

Comment: Thanks @AdamM-W - I'd been thinking similar things. Ideally there'd be an event that could trigger an 'exit' script that would undo all the DOM changes.

Answer (score 9):

Try this in your background script. Many of the old methods have been deprecated now, so I have refactored the code. For my use I'm only installing single content_script file. If need you can iterate over
`chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts` array to get all .js files.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(installScript);

function installScript(details){
    // console.log('Installing content script in all tabs.');
    let params = {
        currentWindow: true
    };
    chrome.tabs.query(params, function gotTabs(tabs){
        let contentjsFile = chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts[0].js[0];
        for (let index = 0; index < tabs.length; index++) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[index].id, {
                file: contentjsFile
            },
            result => {
                const lastErr = chrome.runtime.lastError;
                if (lastErr) {
                    console.error('tab: ' + tabs[index].id + ' lastError: ' + JSON.stringify(lastErr));
                }
            })
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has added a method to listen for the install or upgrade event of the extension. One can re-inject the content script when such an event occur. 
https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled

Answer (score 1):

Due to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=168263, the connection between your content script and background script is severed. As others have mentioned, one way to get around this issue is by reinjecting a content script. A rough overview is detailed in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25844023/1394731).

The main tricky part is that it's necessary to "destruct" your current content script before injecting a new content script. Destructing can be really tricky, so one way to reduce the amount of state you must destruct is by making a small reinjectable script, that talks to your main content script over the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar, but the requirement itself was wrong in my case.
I thought I wanted to pass a message to the content script immediately after installing the app, but in actual what I wanted was to pass message once the page is loaded.
During installation, there is no reason to access the content script.
To achieve this, this is what I did:

1. Adding `webNavigation` to the permission field in manifest.json.
2. listening for webNavigation.complete event in the background script:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener();
```

3. Pass message to the content script from the callback:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      // Send a message to the content script in the active tab to create the modal
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { message: "mymessage" });
    });
  },
  { url: [{ schemes: ["http", "https"] }] })
```

4. Add a listener in the content script

Answer (score -14):

can't you add `?ver=2.10` at the end of css or js you upgraded?

```
"content_scripts": [ {
      "css": [ "css/cs.css?ver=2.10" ],
      "js": [ "js/contentScript.js?ver=2.10" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ],
```