# chrome extensions - is the background script executed again when the extension is updated?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auto-update

Is the background script executed when a Chrome extension is updated?

My extension injects logic to web pages when the background script executes, I am afraid the logic would be injected twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on update the background script is reloaded and executed again.

Existing content scripts are orphaned. There's a [whole big question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22516195/934239) on how to handle that.