# Update an injected iframe from a content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I inject an `<iframe>` on an origin webpage (youtube.com). 
What I want is to:

1. Send an HTTP request to website A.
2. Website A returns a json response.
3. Update the iframe on origin webpage.

I just can't find a way to update iframe from content script.

Part of my manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*"],
    "js": ["jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "content_script.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
],
```

Part of my content script:

```
var iFrame  = document.createElement ("iframe");
iFrame.src  = chrome.extension.getURL("/template.html");
$('#watch-header').after(iFrame);
```

the result of above code:

```
<iframe src="chrome-extension://gdjehplmmeijdoijcnpbehoghnifhmib/template.html"></iframe>
```

I need an iframe so my image inside the template.html can correctly display.
`sendMessage` doesn't work, `contentDocument` also not working.

How to update the iframe anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I was making a similar setup recently, and learned, much to my surprise, that iframes with extension pages inside web pages are treated as **content script contexts**.

Therefore, `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` doesn't reach them. However, `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` does, and it's the best way to communicate from the background page.

If you want to communicate with the content script of the parent page, a good way is to use `postMessage`:

```
// Content script in parent frame
// Assuming you have saved the reference to the frame in iFrame
function messageEmbed(message) {
  iFrame.contentWindow.postMessage(
    message,
    chrome.runtime.getURL("") // Origin of embedded page
  );
}

// Script in embedded HTML page
function messagePage(message) {
  window.parent.postMessage(
    message,
    "http://example.com/" // The expected origin of embedding page
                          // Can use "*" if not known in advance
  );
}

// Listener in both
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // Use event.data here as the message
});
```

Be warned that a hostile page can message the embed as well and there's no way to distinguish it save for [using pre-shared key crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30529003/934239). It's an unlikely risk though.

---

Final note, you mention the following:

> I need an iframe so my image inside the template.html can correctly display

You may need to look into [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources), perhaps you don't need this complication!

Comment: Thank you!, I will try your method and see what happend, and then come back tell you it is work or not