# Webextension inline install chrome.runtime.connect issues

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having a really weird issue, I've developped a webextension that uses messaging between content script and background script (using `chrome.runtime.connect`) and nativemessaging.

The issue i'm facing is that when I install the extension (manually from the store beforehand and then connect to my website, everything works as expected, the chrome.runtime.connect works and returns a valid port to the background script.

But when i do an inline install of the extension from my website to get around the fact to have to navigate to have the content script in the webpage, i manually inject the content script into my page using

```
 function injectContentScript() {
             var s = document.createElement("script");
             s.setAttribute("src", "chrome-extension://<extensionid>/content.js");
             document.head.appendChild(s);
         }
```

and the exact same content script but manually injected doesn't behave the same. chrome.runtime.connect returns a null object and chrome.runtime.lastError gives me

> Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

I'm calling on the sender side (content.js - manually injected content script) `chrome.runtime.connect(extensionID)` where extension id is the id of the extension generated by the chrome webstore. And on the receiving side (background.js - extension background script) `chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(onPortConnected);`

I'm not really sure how to debug this issue, maybe it's a timing issue?
The background script is well executed even with the inline install (i've added logs and debugged it through the background.html in chrome extension manager)

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the _sending_ side is and how it's executed.

Comment: indeed, (i just edited the question)  but yes the "sending" side is the content script and the "receiving" side is the background script. hope that's a bit clearer

Comment: You should _not_ provide the extension ID to `connect()` inside the extension! That's only for cross-extension messaging. Also, it's unclear when this happens to you after the install.

Comment: oh wow how did i miss that.. ok this might explain the weird behaviour i'll try without it! As for your other question, the sequence is basically 1. install 2. send a msg from website to extension (content script) 3. content script  sends a msg to background script.

Comment: Ah, you may be misunderstanding something. Content scripts are _not_ injected on install into matching pages. Only new navigations since install will have content scripts running. Are you trying to send this message without navigating after install?

Comment: Ah yes this part i'm aware of. after the inline install i manually inject the content script into my page so that it's available. The content script is listed in the manifest under content script and web_accessible_resources.

Comment: This again rings some alarm bells. Can you include the injection code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152740/discussion-between-meekaah-and-xan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two scenarios.

1. Your content script `content.js` is executed as normal upon navigation, as a content script defined in the manifest.

   In this case, it executes in a special JS context attached to the page and reserved for your content scripts. See [Execution Environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) docs section for explanation. It is isolated from the webpage and is considered part of the extension (albeit with lower privileges).

   When you connect from a content script, `chrome.runtime.connect()` is treated as *internal* communication between parts of the extension. So while you can provide the extension ID, it is not needed.

   More importantly, the event raised in this case is `chrome.runtime.onConnect`.
2. Your supposed "inject content script immediately" code called from the webpage does something completely different.

   Instead of creating a new execution context, the code is instead added directly to the page; it is *not* considered part of the extension and has no access to extension API.

   Normally, a call to `chrome.runtime.connect()` would simply fail, as this is not a function exposed to webpages; however, you also declared `externally_connectable`, so it is exposed *specifically* to your webpage.

   In this case, passing the extension ID is *mandatory* for the `connect`. You were doing this already, so the call was succeeding.

   However, and that's what made it fail: the corresponding event is no longer `onConnect`, but `onConnectExternal`!

What you *should* be doing is:

- Not mixing code that is run in very different contexts.
- If you need communication from the webpage to background, always do it from the webpage, not sometimes-from-content-sometimes-from-page.

  That way you only have to listen to `onConnectExternal` and it cuts out the need for a content script (if it was its only function).

  See the docs as well: [Sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).
- You don't have to source the code from `chrome-extension://<extensionid>/`; you can directly add this to your website's code and potentially avoid `web_accessible_resources`.

And if you actually want to *inject content scripts on first run*, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23895822/934239).

Related reading: [How to properly handle chrome extension updates from content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516195/how-to-properly-handle-chrome-extension-updates-from-content-scripts)