# Does content script and background script maintain its communication after user updates to a new version?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

We're currently developing a chrome extension, and one question that was raised was do content scripts remain connected to background script if the user updates his extension to a new version?

Does both background script and content script gets reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, entire extension is being restarted. However content scripts don't get removed/restarted until page they are running in is refreshed.

Comment: Thanks, I see, in that case what the best way to also update the content script once the extension has been updated?

Comment: Perhaps a background script could send a message to content script to refresh the page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516195/how-to-properly-handle-chrome-extension-updates-from-content-scripts

Comment: The old content scripts can't send messages. Their sendMessage or any other `chrome` method will throw an exception. See [Chrome extension: How to remove orphaned script after chrom extension update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471345) and [Chrome extension content script re-injection after upgrade or install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10994324)