# Can't communicate through the content.js and background.js, after i disable the extension then enable it in chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What i am trying to do is,

**Popup.html**

> In popup.html i created a logIn page, after user click the LogIn button i successfully loggedIn at that time in local storage i store my token and username.

**content.js**

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function (response) {
            // console.log('Data to Call', response, dialingNumber);
            if (response == undefined || response == null) {
                window.confirm('Please LogIn...!');
            }
            else {
// ....
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
            var credentials = localStorage.getItem('voi-auth').split("|");
            console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
            if (request.greeting == "hello")
                sendResponse({farewell: credentials});
        });
```

> It's working fine at the time i first installed, able to call the credential which i store in local storage from the content script.

**Problem**

> My problem is that if i went to the extension and disable the extension then again enable it , i can't communicate between content and background scripts , response is undefined in content script when i call the send message function, even though the local storage has the token and username. Sad part is it will work fine, only when i inspect the background.js and make it open all the time. It won't work when i close my popup.

**Is there any solution to avoid this suitation something like execute the background page like that?**

Comment: This is a known problem in Chrome and you can find several answers here on StackOverflow ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994324/chrome-extension-content-script-re-injection-after-upgrade-or-install)). In short, reinject your content scripts explicitly using chrome.tabs.executeScript in the background page.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Is it applicable when i disable/enable my extension

Comment: @wOxxOm, i mean are you sure the code you provide will work, Anyway that's not solving my problem.

Comment: @wOxxOm, actually my problem is with background.js not  content.js

Comment: I'm too lazy to convince you that the underlying problem is the same so hopefully someone else will help here.

Comment: BTW you can store the data in chrome.storage.local and thus there'll be no need for communication because the content scripts can access chrome.storage.local of the extension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173890/discussion-between-sangeeth-john-and-woxxom).