# Chrome Extension: How to remove orphaned script after Chrome extension update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with a popup page which passes a boolean variable to my content page via simple one-time requests. The content page would then do some action based on the status of the boolean variable passed from the popup page. This was working perfectly until I accidentally removed the extension (still in developer mode, the extension is unpacked) and had to re-load it.

This caused an **extension context invalidated error** to appear in the popup inspection console and the webpage console seems to validate that the popup page and content script are not communicating. The webpage with the chrome extension active shows this error: **Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received**.

Based on a few answers I've already seen, it seems that reloading my chrome extension has "orphaned" my original working content script from the rest of my extension, which causes the aforementioned "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received." error on the webpage console.

I believe that I cannot just reinject my content script again as my content script has DOM event listeners. Is there a possible way to remove the currently running orphan script? Or is there any suggested workaround to this problem?

Here is my popup.js:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'currentWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {cTabSettings: (some boolean variable)});
});
```

Here is my content.js:

```js
// Listening for message from popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.cTabSettings === true) {
      enabled = true;
    } else if (request.cTabSettings === false) {
      enabled = false;
    }
});

// DOM listener and action
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
   // Some action
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({sender: "content", selText : "blah"}, function () {
      console.log("success");
   });
}, false);
```

I am using chrome developer mode version 76. Just to rephrase, this chrome extension **was working** (content script communicates with popup) before I accidentally reloaded it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the orphaned content script can still receive DOM messages, send one from your new working content script to the ghosted content script via `window`, for example. Upon receiving the message you'll unregister all listeners (and nullify any global variables) which will also make your old script eligible for automatic garbage collection.

background.js:

See how to re-inject content scripts on reloading/installing the extension in [this example](/a/11598753).

content.js:

```
var orphanMessageId = chrome.runtime.id + 'orphanCheck';
window.dispatchEvent(new Event(orphanMessageId));
window.addEventListener(orphanMessageId, unregisterOrphan);

// register all listeners with named functions to preserve their object reference
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessage);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

// the popup script checks it to see if a usable instance of content script is running
window.running = true;

function unregisterOrphan() {
  if (chrome.runtime.id) {
    // someone tried to kick us out but we're not orphaned! 
    return;
  }
  window.removeEventListener(orphanMessageId, unregisterOrphan);
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  try {
    // 'try' is needed to avoid an exception being thrown in some cases 
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(onMessage);
  } catch (e) {}
  return true;
}

function onMessage(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  //...........
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
  // DOM events still fire in the orphaned content script after the extension
  // was disabled/removed and before it's re-enabled or re-installed
  if (unregisterOrphan()) { return }
  //...........
}
```

popup.js should ensure a content script is injected before sending a message:

```
async function sendMessage(data) {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  if (await ensureContentScript(tab.id)) {
    return await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, data);
  }
}

async function ensureContentScript(tabId) {
  try {
    const [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId},
      func: () => window.running === true,
    });
    if (!result) {
      await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId},
        files: ['content.js'],
      });
    }
    return true;
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

Comment: I keep running across your content @wOxxOm thank you, it's a ton of help so far! Wish this weird edge case wasn't such a pain though. I keep running into one thing after the next. First I fixed up the issue with context going away on extension reloading, but now I'm running into old events still around trying to access the old context uhgg. I was still hoping to do some cleanup before the old context went away, but if I'm understanding right, the new script should be injected, and I just need to handle the old stuff ie: remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64407849/1114817)

It's not about removal of script but to avoiding error in case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) I was able to properly handle removing the old event handler. I currently experience this issue due to trying to handle another issue that stemmed from re-injecting scripts when the extension reloads see: [Chrome extension content script re-injection after upgrade or install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994324/chrome-extension-content-script-re-injection-after-upgrade-or-install)

### Content Script Code

```js
function onUnloadHandler() {
  if (chrome.runtime.id) {
    // perform cleanup here; save things, etc
  }
  else {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onUnloadHandler);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onUnloadHandler);
```

### Explanation

This code is a basic example of handling some cleanup before the window closes, while also detecting if the old event handler is still in place and removing it. If utilizing the reinjection technique listed above there will be a new handler in place to handle the cleanup. Technically when this initially fires there will be the new handler and the old. We must make sure the old handler is removed and does not try to interact with the old `chrome.runtime` that is now disconnected. Utilizing `window.removeEventListener` is a better method than checking fo `chrome.runtime.id` and just returning. Otherwise these handlers would continue stacking up on pages every time the extension reloaded/reinjected. By utilizing the `window.removeEventLister` the garbage collector can clean it up.

### One Gotcha

One thing to be mindful of is that upon extension reload you will now have your new script re-injected, but the old handler code will be on the page, so it's possible you may need to give a restart of the extension, refresh the page (which will contain the old handler), restart the extension again, refresh the page -- this will now kick off the new handler.