# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sync')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my injected content script, I'm attempting to use the chrome storage api:

content.js

```
document.addEventListener("paste", (event) => {
        let paste = event.clipboardData.getData('text');
        var lookalike = isLikeWallet(paste)
        if (lookalike) {
            chrome.storage.sync.get("wallets", (items) => {
                var wallets = items.wallets;
                if(!wallets.includes(paste)) {
                    alert('alert')
                }
            });
        }
});
```

It worked the last time I tested it - a few days ago. Now I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sync')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (contentScript.js:10)
```

This storage API seems to be the accepted method for accessing shared state variables across your background, popup, and content scripts, and the documentation states: (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/)

> Your extension's content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page.

I.e. I don't need to use the messaging API to send data back and forth.

Here's my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Test extension",
    "description": "Description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab"],
      "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "/images/test16.png",
            "32": "/images/test32.png",
            "48": "/images/test48.png",
            "128": "/images/test128.png"
          }
      },
      "icons": {
        "16": "/images/test16.png",
        "32": "/images/test32.png",
        "48": "/images/test48.png",
        "128": "/images/test128.png"
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
      ]
  }
```

Thank you in advance for any help! Not sure what's going on here - especially since it worked (and reliably) just a few days ago.

Comment: Looks like you add a `<script>` element with this code inside. Such code is just a normal web page script, not a content script, so it can't use chrome.storage API.

Comment: Thanks for the potential fix! Looked through my `html` file, which is popup.html, and the only script element is for `popup.js`. Any other ideas??

Comment: The popup script is an extension page so its scripts are not content scripts. Content scripts run only in web pages i.e. http:// and https:// sites, not in the extension pages.

Comment: yep, just mentioned that b/c I don't think i'm referencing `content.js` with a `<script>` element anywhere. I can see the injected script in sources when I inspect the webpage. My confusion is that I've verified the script is injected into the page, and on manifest.json it's marked as a content script - so why can't I use the chrome.storage API? once again, really appreciate the help thinking through this

Comment: The only other reasons are a bug in the browser or you didn't reload the extension after adding the `storage` permission or you look at an old error in chrome://extensions page UI.

Comment: thanks for the list! I went back to a git revision where the functionality was working correctly, then went back to the current revision where it wasn't (and updated and reloaded the extension each time), and now it works again. argh...

Comment: When you reload or update the extension your old content script's event listeners such as `paste` remain so when the listener is triggered it no longer belongs to the current extension, it's "orphaned" and it can't use chrome API. See [Chrome extension: How to remove orphaned script after chrom extension update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471345)

Comment: Ah ok - thank you for the help! I haven't yet been able to reproduce it, but when I do I'll give that a try

Comment: When/if you do, please [edit] your question to update it. This comment chain is getting rather long.