# chrome.runtime.sendmessage not working in chrome extentions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

hello I have a question
I send to backgroud.js from content.js;
but it is append error :  Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

but it works fine that i think

content.js send chrome.runtime.sendMessage
background.js receive chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener and menifest.json

chrome.runtime.sendMessage is it does not work

```
"background": { "service_worker": "background.bundle.js" },
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.bundle.js"],
      "css": ["content.styles.css"]
    }
  ],
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  switch (request.action) {
      case "item-save": {
          chrome.storage.local.get('item', function (itemData) {
              let itemList = [];

              if (Object.keys(itemData).length > 0) {
                  itemList = itemData.item;
              }

              itemList.push(request.source);

              chrome.storage.local.set({
                  item: itemList
              });

              sendResponse("OK");
          });

          return true;
      }

      case "page-main": {
          chrome.tabs.create({
              url: chrome.runtime.getURL("options.html"),
          });

          return true;
      }

      default: return true;
  }
});
```

content.js

```
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            action : "item-save",
            source : item
        },function(response){
            if(response ==="OK"){

                let ok = confirm("check")
                
                // if(ok){
                //     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                        
                //         action : "page-main",
                //     });
                    
                // }
            }
        })
    })


what's wrong?
```

Comment: The most likely reason is that you reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page but didn't remove your old content script, so it still reacts to the click. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471345) for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common `chrome.runtime.onMessage` bug that hopefully gets fixed one day.

I guess it gives an error when `request.action` is `"page-main"`, since it's waiting for a `sendResponse`.

I think the solution would be to add an empty `sendResponse()` on `"page-main"`.

You can also just use a `return true;` outside the `switch` and make it less redundant.:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  switch (request.action) {
    case "item-save": {
      chrome.storage.local.get("item", function (itemData) {
        // your code here ...
        sendResponse("OK");
      });
      break;
    }
    case "page-main": {
      chrome.tabs.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("options.html"),
      });
      sendResponse(); // or try with sendResponse({})
      break;
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

Also the [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) functions are asynchronous.

So on `"item-save"` the `sendResponse("OK");` will be executed before the `chrome.storage.local.set`.

If you want to run `sendResponse` after saving the `itemList`, it would be something like this:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({
  item: itemList,
}, function () {
  sendResponse("OK");
});
```

I hope it works! :)

Comment: Can you please tell my isse? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72846615/chrome-extension-uncaught-in-promise-error-could-not-establish-connection-r?noredirect=1#comment128668904_72846615