# Extension context invalidated - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a screen capture chrome extension and it takes screenshots on the document "onClick" event.

Currently, I'm sending an event from my "popup script" and receiving it in the content script as you can see.

but after reloading the extension or updating it, I get the Extension context invalidated on each document click. reloading the tab will fix it but it's not the desired solution.
this is my content script:

```
const sendMessage = (e) => {
  try {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      type: "screenshot"
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error", e);
  }
};

const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  sendMessage(e);
};

const handleMessage = (request) => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick, true);
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
```

I tried every solution that I find but didn't work perfectly. and I think this is a chrome bug, why they don't fix it?

Comment: See [How to remove orphaned script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471345) and also use [re-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10994324).

Comment: @wOxxOm I'll try again these solutions. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the extension and the current page solved my problem, and if it does not work you can try to close and open the browser back. I'm sure that will solve your problem

Comment: That is just a description of the problem, certainly not a solution: the fact that restarting browser is need IS the problem. Plus, the OP clearly stated that they know that closing/reopening tab solve unlock the situation, that they do not consider (rightfuly so) this a solution. How would closing/reopening the whole browser could be better?

Answer (score 0):

Most the time this happens when you make changes in your code and send messages without restarting the extension

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).