# Where do I need to add `if(chrome.runtime.id == undefined) return;` for Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This post is connected to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74768287/how-to-get-the-updated-html-if-a-button-was-clicked-inside-of-an-event-listener?noredirect=1#comment131957740_74768287). I am creating a Chrome extension. I want to insert text into the Gmail reply field - based on a click. I use `MutationObserver` for getting the changes and not only the initial HTML. Since I implemented `MutationObserver` I get the error:

`content.js:63 Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated. at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (content.js:63:20)`

Like its stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64407849/14606987). I tried to insert `if (chrome.runtime.id == undefined) return;` for avoiding the error. But it's not working. Where do I need to add the insert `if (chrome.runtime.id == undefined) return;`?

**content.js**

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.innerText == "Reply") {
    const element = document.querySelector(".a3s.aiL");
    const textContent = element.textContent;
    const allElements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      const insertField = allElements.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.classList.contains("aO7")) {
          console.log("found it");
        }
      });
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
    });

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      type: "click_event",
    });
  }
});
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.type == "click_event") {
    console.log("click event captured in current webpage");
  }
});
```

Comment: You can wrap the call that sends the message `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(..)` in the content script in an `if` statement that checks for this condition.

Comment: Hm okay, still same error. @Titus

Comment: You probably still have some content scripts injected in that page that don't have this check. After you make this change, you'll have to refresh the extension and then refresh the webpage the content script is injected in.

Comment: The check should be inside MutationObserver callback.