# Chrome Extension Send Message is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing chrome extension.
I want to send message from `content.js` to `background.js` but it's not working.

**If I click on the plugin icon and click on the button I added to YouTube with the popup open, the message is sent to background.js.
But I have to click the plugin icon again for the message to be sent every time.**

**content.js**

```
if(location.hostname.includes("youtube.com")){
    document.addEventListener('yt-navigate-finish', process);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', process);

    function process() {
        if (!location.pathname.startsWith('/watch')) {
        return;
        }

        if(document.getElementById("yt-btn-music-12atv") == null) {
            var yt_btn_music = document.createElement("button");
            yt_btn_music.innerHTML = "Keşif Kuyruğu";
            yt_btn_music.id = "yt-btn-music-12atv";
        } else {yt_btn_music = document.getElementById("yt-btn-music-12atv");}

        document.getElementById("below").insertBefore(yt_btn_music, document.getElementById("below").firstChild);

        document.getElementById("yt-btn-music-12atv").addEventListener("click", function() {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({request: "call-func_openMusic"});
        });
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
function openMusic() {
    openTab("https://www.youtube.com/" + music, "Şarkı Köşesi", "www.youtube.com");
    if(lastMusics.length >= 10) {
        lastMusics.shift();
    }
    if(lastMusics.includes(music) == false) {
        lastMusics.push(music);
    }
    setStorage();
    loadStorage();
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(response, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (response.request === "call-func_openMusic")
            openMusic();
            sendResponse();
        }
);
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "Şimdiye kadar yapılmış en özel akıllı tahta eklentisi...",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "options_page": "popup.html#settings",

  "background.service_worker": {
    "scripts": ["/js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": [ "/js/content.js" ],
    "css": [ "/css/content.css" ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],

  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
    
  "icons": {
    "16": "/img/16.png",
    "48": "/img/48.png",
    "128": "/img/128.png"
  },

  "action": {
    "default_title": "Extension",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "/img/16.png",
        "48": "/img/48.png",
        "128": "/img/128.png"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us openMusic and if it's not in background.js indicate where it is and how you load that other file. Also check the [background console](/a/10258029).

Comment: The openMusic() function is in background.js and works correctly. But when I add alert("message") instead of openMusic function it still doesn't work

Comment: Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated.

Comment: You can't use `alert` in ManifestV3 background script. Use devtools of the background script to set breakpoints and debug the code. The context error is caused by reloading of the extension, see [How to remove orphaned script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471345) + [Chrome extension content script re-injection after upgrade or install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10994324)

Comment: chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) { 
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {tabId: tabs.id},
            files: "/js/content.js",
        });
    });
});

Comment: No, this won't work because the active tab may be chrome://extensions, please refer to the links I gave.

Comment: Popup.html runs every time I click the button when it is opened. It doesn't work if I don't click on the plugin icon.

Comment: The popup page is completely unrelated. Are you loading content.js or background.js in the popup? If so, it's a mistake. Make sure your question contains a full [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: I updated my question. Can you review my question again?

Comment: You didn't show where you declare/load background.js. If you do it in popup.html then it's a mistake. It should be **only** in manifest.json in `background` section, see the documentation.

Comment: No, content.js and popup.html have no code relationship. With content.js, the plugin detects that the page is a youtube page and adds a button to the page accordingly. When users click the button, it triggers the openMusic() function in background.js, which is used to open songs on youtube. This function is working correctly. But the problem is why the message is not sent to background.js without clicking the plugin icon. So when I open the plugin with the mouse and click the button while the plugin is open, a message is sent and the openMusic() function works. I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: You didn't confirm whether you load background.js in popup.html or not, but judging by manifest.json you do, and that is a mistake #1. Mistake #2 is `background.service_worker` declaration, which is completely invalid. See the correct example [in this documentation article](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#manifest).

Answer (score 0):

My test results contradict your claims.

I have one question.
You are sending a response but not receiving it.

[image]

index.html

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="yt-btn-music-12atv">button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

background.js

```js
const openMusic = () => {
  console.log("openMusic");
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (response, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (response.request === "call-func_openMusic")
      openMusic(); //the function is working
    sendResponse();
  }
);
```

content.js

```js
document.getElementById("yt-btn-music-12atv").addEventListener("click", function () {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ request: "call-func_openMusic" });
});
```

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Popup.html runs every time I click the button when it is opened. It doesn't work if I don't click on the plugin icon.

Comment: Popup.html?
It doesn't exist in your post.

Comment: I updated my question. Can you review my question again?

Comment: Please post manifest.json, popup.html and pupup.js.

Comment: No, content.js and popup.html have no code relationship. With content.js, the plugin detects that the page is a youtube page and adds a button to the page accordingly. When users click the button, it triggers the openMusic() function in background.js, which is used to open songs on youtube. This function is working correctly. But the problem is why the message is not sent to background.js without clicking the plugin icon. So when I open the plugin with the mouse and click the button while the plugin is open, a message is sent and the openMusic() function works.

Comment: I added manifest.json

Comment: Please post popup.html and pupup.js.