# Error: Extension context invalidated, from chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/admin.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, error-handling, sentry

According to Sentry, our react application has reported this error 700 times in the last 24 hours, from 2 users:

```
Error: Extension context invalidated.
  at Object._updateMetadata(chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/admin.js:16:202361)
  at ? (chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/admin.js:16:202179)
  at c(chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/admin.js:16:141364)
  at x._settlePromiseFromHandler(chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/admin.js:16:114161)
  at x._settlePromiseAt(chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/admin.js:16:115434)
  at x._settlePromises(chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/admin.js:16:117279)
  at a._drainQueue(chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/admin.js:16:74218)
  at a._drainQueues(chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/admin.js:16:74279)
  at drainQueues(chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/admin.js:16:72590)
```

It seems that the error is being thrown in the `chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/admin.js` script, which suggests that this extension is causing the problem?

Is this safe to ignore in Sentry? If not, what are the alternative options for handling this error? If the error is caused by a chrome extension that is completely unrelated to our react application, how could we possibly do anything other than to ignore the error in Sentry?

Comment: It's unrelated to your web app. This error is caused by a mistake in the extension: it doesn't handle its "[orphaned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471345)" content script after the extension is auto-updated by the browser. You can suggest the authors of the extension to incorporate the fix I've linked.

Comment: how would I figure out which extension is causing the issue? `haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh` isn't too helpful on the surface

Comment: Just google this id. I did now and apparently it was a malware that's already deleted from the store.

Comment: [related on GitHub](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/2380#issuecomment-619198689), [and another one](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/2210#issuecomment-716943611) from googling "`google chrome extension store "haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh"`"

Answer (score -1):

chrome-extension://haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh/ is the extension GoGuardian, used by schools to monitor what people are doing on school computers.

Answer (score -1):

haldlgldplgnggkjaafhelgiaglafanh is GoGuardian, a extension that schools use on student chromebooks. I found this site when i searched up the ID

Comment: ... what is the point of this answer post? the only way it differs from the one that was posted months ago is that it says "on student chromebooks"... But why should the answer be limited to Chromebooks?