# Chrome extension simple script not being injected

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying my first steps in writing a minimal Chrome extension, and I cannot figure out why it does not execute my clientScript.js.

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Sit back, relax and enjoy",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Finds and clicks the +extra channel points button when it is available",
    "permissions": [ "activeTab" ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "https://twitch.tv/*" ],
            "js": [ "contentScript.js" ],
            "run_at": "document_idle"
        }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And this is the the script that I want executed on pages that match `https://twitch.tv/*`:

```
let intervalTimer

function sibareaen() {
    const btn = document.querySelector('.tw-button.tw-button--success.tw-interactive')
    if (btn) {
        btn.click()
        console.log('At your service - clicked the button for you!')
    }
}

function toggleSibareaen(on) {
    switch (on) {
        case true:
            intervalTimer = setInterval(sibareaen, 750)
            break
        case false:
            clearInterval(intervalTimer)
            break
        default:
            clearInterval(intervalTimer)
    }
}
console.log('At your service - ready to click for you!')
toggleSibareaen(true)
```

I have both files in the same folder:

[image: folder structure]

Also, I have properly "installed" the extension:

[image]

The console shows no errors related to the extension.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you did reload the tab (the content scripts are injected only on initial tab load, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11598753) for more info and a workaround), you're probably a victim of the [infamous Google's decision to hide `www`](https://crbug.com/883038) in the address bar: if you enter the edit mode and select/copy the entire text (or simply double-click the address) you will see the site's URL is actually `https://www.twitch.tv/` so your manifest.json has an incorrect URL pattern that doesn't match the real site.

Simply use a generalized pattern like `"https://*.twitch.tv/*"` that will match both `https://www.twitch.tv/` and `https://twitch.tv/` and any other subdomain(s).

P.S. as a debugging step, you can check if the content script is even injected by looking at the context selector in devtools console toolbar or in devtools -> Sources -> Content scripts panel. And if you want to restore the classic address bar behavior, see https://superuser.com/a/1498561

Comment: The site's URL is actually `https://twitch.tv` and the script is not available in the sources panel of the developer tools.

Comment: @connexo, assuming you did reload the tab (the content scripts are injected  only on initial tab load) your comment can only mean that the site URL used in your manifest.json is incorrect. And I see `www` in the site's URL following the steps mentioned in my answer: https://puu.sh/F1763/6bdef2cf17.png