# Chrome Extensions "chrome.storage.local" data updating trouble

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

I am working on one chrome extension and i need to use local storage to send data from options page to background scritps.

Options page script:

```
function addToStorage(key, val){
    let obj = {};
    obj[key] = val;

    chrome.storage.local.set( obj, function() {
      if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(
          "Error setting " + key + " to " + JSON.stringify(val) +
          ": " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message
        );
      }
    });
}
```

Background:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('code', function(code) {
    ... with code.code ...
});
```

For example:
Now `chrome.storage.local` `code` value is `abcd`
I'm performing `addToStorage('code', '1234')` from options page script
After that in background script value `code` only will change when i manually click "update" at chrome extesions page

How can i automatically get actual data at background script?

Comment: Your current background script is wrong or rather doesn't do anything meaningful/useful. The background script runs in a separate hidden background page. A persistent background script runs when a) the browser profile starts, b) when the extension is re-enabled, or c) installed. So, your code immediately queries the storage at that moment, before it is set by the options script. You need to use API events or remove the background script. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63966400) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

the background script will check only once when started as is.

You could pass a mesage from the options script to background scripts after you update the local storage and use that as a trigger to check storage.

try this:

Options page

```
function addToStorage(key, val){
    let obj = {};
    obj[key] = val;

    chrome.storage.local.set( obj, function() {
      if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(
          "Error setting " + key + " to " + JSON.stringify(val) +
          ": " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message
        );
      }
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({status: "Storage Updated"}, function (responce) {
          console.log(responce);
      })
    });
}
```

Background Page:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, responce) {
        if (request.status === "Storage Updated") {
            chrome.storage.local.get('code', function(code) {
                // ... with code.code ...
            });

            sendResponce({status: "Update Recieved"});
        }
    }
);
```

Hope that helps, message passing docs here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging