# Content script doesn't communicate with background script - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I'm trying to send new tab URL from background.js to content.js. The .sendMessage() performs but doesn't get to the content.js

background.js:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (changeInfo.url) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
                url: changeInfo.url
            })
        }
    }
);
```

content.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, callback) {
    console.log('here');
  });
```

manifest.json:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Url tracker",
  "description": "Track your latest visited URLs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo-small.png",
    "48": "logo-small.png",
    "128": "logo-small.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Content scripts run after DOMContentLoaded by default ([it can be changed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time)) but the URL is reported to onUpdated when the tab starts loading i.e. before the content script runs.

   The solution is to add a check to skip the first update because it's not needed: an instance of the content script runs in each matching web page and it already knows `location.href` of its page.

   ```js
   if (changeInfo.url && tab.status === 'complete') {
   ```
2. After you reload your extension on chrome://extensions page (or update it from the web store), all its content scripts get "orphanized" and can't receive messages.

   The solution is to [re-inject them explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994324/chrome-extension-content-script-re-injection-after-upgrade-or-install).