# Chrome Extension gives two errors: Uncaught TypeError and Unchecked runtime.lastError

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am facing two errors on Chrome extension that I am building:

Error 1:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')
> Context
> _generated_background_page.html
> Stack Trace
> popup.js:3 (anonymous function)

Error 2:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
> Context
> _generated_background_page.html
> Stack Trace
> _generated_background_page.html:0 (anonymous function)

I have already checked the questions on this site that address these two errors and I tried the solutions provided in them, but I am still facing the two errors.

My original code:-

popup.js (tried changing from `onclick` to `onClicked` for error 1, tried putting this code in `window.onload` for error 2)

```
let populateBtn = document.getElementById('populateBtn');
let textArea = document.getElementById('productList');
populateBtn.onclick = function(element) {
    let color = element.target.value;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        if(!textArea.value) 
        {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(
                tabs[0].id,
                {code: 'alert("Please, populate the order list!");'});
            return;
        }
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {data: textArea.value.replace(/\t/g,'').split("\n")}, function(response) {
        });
    });
};
```

background.html (tried putting `<script>` after `</body>` tag for error 1)

```
<body>
    <p>Gina's Bakery Bulk Order</p>
    <textarea id="productList"></textarea>
    <button id="populateBtn">Create Order</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

app.js (tried `chrome.runtime.connect` for error 2)

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
});
```

inject.js (tried `chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener` for error 2)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    let failed = [];
    request.data.forEach(element => { // iterate over all products
        if(element.includes('-')){
            let data = element.split('-');
            let quantity = data[0].toLowerCase().replace("gb", "").trim();
            let ID = data[1].trim();
            let elementName = 'pid_' + ID.replace(".", "_");
            if(document.getElementsByName(elementName).length > 0) 
                document.getElementsByName(elementName)[0].value = quantity;
            else        
                failed.push("<td>GB-"+ ID +"</td><td>" + quantity + "</td>");
        }
     });   
    if(failed.length > 0){
        //alert("Order unsuccessful! One or more products are not ordered: " + failed.join(", "));
        let modal = document.createElement("div");
        modal.setAttribute("id", "failedOrderModal");
        modal.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed;width:250px;left:50%;top:100px;background-color:#fff;border-radius:10px;padding:10px;z-index:10000;color:#000;border: 1px solid red;text-align:center;");
        let head = document.createElement("h2");
        head.innerText = "Order unsuccessful! One or more products were not found!";
        modal.appendChild(head);
        let table = document.createElement("table");
        let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
        table.appendChild(tbody);
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tr.innerHTML = "<td>ITEM</td><td>QTY</td>";
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        failed.forEach(failedItem => {
            tr = document.createElement("tr");
            tr.innerHTML = failedItem;
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
        });
        modal.appendChild(table);
        let closeBtn = document.createElement("button");
        closeBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        closeBtn.innerText = "Close";
        closeBtn.onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById("failedOrderModal").remove();
        }
        modal.appendChild(closeBtn);
        document.body.appendChild(modal);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("All products were successfuly populated!");  
    }   
    sendResponse({result: "ok"})
    return true;
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Gina's Bakery Order",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Helps automate orders from ginas-bakery.com.au",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["app.js", "popup.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/ginas-bakery_16.png",
        "32": "images/ginas-bakery_32.png",
        "48": "images/ginas-bakery_48.png",
        "128": "images/ginas-bakery_128.png"
      },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "background.html"
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://www.ginas-bakery.com.au/order/"],
            "js": ["inject.js"]
        }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

None of the above mentioned solutions worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background script page is an invisible hidden page, so running visible scripts like app.js or popup.js there is meaningless. Remove `background` section from manifest.json and rename your background.html to popup.html both on the disk and in manifest.json.

manifest.json:

```json
{
  "name": "Gina's Bakery Order",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
  "browser_action": {"default_popup": "popup.html"},
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Content scripts run only when the page loads, so if you just reloaded or installed/updated the extension without reloading the tab, the content scripts won't run there.

Although you can [inject them explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10994324), it's much better to switch to programmatic injection on demand (use executeScript instead of `content_scripts`) because you can do it without requiring any host permissions when installing the extension.

popup.js:

```js
const textArea = document.getElementById('productList');
const btn = document.getElementById('populateBtn');
btn.onclick = () => {
  const data = textArea.value.replace(/\t/g, '').split('\n');
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ([tab]) => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {data}, () => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'inject.js'}, () => {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {data});
        });
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Since you're not using the response in sendMessage, don't send it in the first place, i.e. remove `sendResponse({result: "ok"}); return true;` from inject.js.