# How to send data from popup.js to content.js in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that will auto fill a input on a page (the outlook subject line in this case), and I need to somehow pass the message that I get from the input on popup.js (the extension), into the content.js so that I can update the DOM on that page.

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter a message..." class="message-input">
        <input type="submit" value="Set new message" id="message-btn" class="message-btn">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="popup.js"></script>

</html>
```

popup.js

```
let messageInput = document.getElementsByClassName('message-input')[0];
let updateMessageBtn = document.getElementById('message-btn');

updateMessageBtn.addEventListener('click', async(messageInput) => {
        // Query tab
    let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
    let tabs = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);

    // Open up connection
    const port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id, {
        name: "uiOps",
    });

        port.postMessage({
            message: messageInput.value
        });

            port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        if (msg.exists) {
            alert('Exists');
        } else {
            alert("Doesn't exist");
        }
    })
});
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    if (port.name === "uiOps") {
      const idToQuery = msg.message;
      if (idToQuery) {
        port.postMessage({
          exists: true,
        });
      } else {
        port.postMessage({
          exists: false,
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Email Autofiller",
    "description": "Automatically fill email subject lines!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
        "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
    },
      "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  }
}
```

I've tried a ton of different things, including trying to use localstorage, which didn't work. I think I'm on the right track, but the Google Chrome Extension docs are confusing me a little. Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: You didn't declare/inject the content script. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71273588) for a solution based on one-time messaging, which should be sufficient in the majority of cases.

Comment: @wOxxOm so in my popup.js I need to modify the updateMessageBtn.addEventListener to declare/inject the content.js script, correct? How would I pass in the value that is in the messageInput variable on popup.js, and then use it in the content.js to dynamically update the subject line? That's what I'm still confused on, even after reading that answer. Edit: I see that you are passing in the data with the chrome.tabs.sendMessage, but I am unsure of how to access that from my content.js if that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry I'm not understanding it perfectly. Can you give an example of how I would access a variable in my content.js file that I passed from my popup.js like this? ```let data = 'hello world'; chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'content.js'}, () => {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {data});
        });```

Comment: `data` is a property in that example, so use `msg.data`, assuming `msg` is the name of the parameter. The answer doesn't show the parts that are ok in the original question.

Comment: Sorry @wOxxOm I’m still very confused on the whole thing

Comment: Use chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg => ....) in your content script.

Comment: Hey @AustinCodes, I have tried to write a concrete example. Give it a look and tell me if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

I'll share a working example that I just tested out. The code below allows popup.js to send a message to content.js, and vice versa.

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ImageOps</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pico.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Test</button>
    <p id="p"></p>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let p = document.getElementById('p');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    send({
        doSomething: true
    });
});

async function send(message) {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true });
    const response = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, message);
    // Optional: do something with response
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.finishedDoingSomething) {
        p.textContent = "All done doing something.";
    }
    // Optional: sendResponse({message: "goodbye"});
});

/**************************************************************************
Functions to inject content.js script
***************************************************************************/
async function getCurrentTab() {
    let queryOptions = { active: true };
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
    return tab;
};

function injectContentScript(tab) {
    const { id, url } = tab;
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
        {
            target: { tabId: id, allFrames: true },
            files: ['content.js']
        }
    );
};

getCurrentTab().then((tab) => {
    injectContentScript(tab);
});
```

content.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.doSomething) {
        doSomething();
    }
    // Optional: sendResponse({message: "goodbye"});
});

function doSomething() {
    console.log("The doSomething() function is being called.");
    send({
        finishedDoingSomething: true
    });
}

async function send(message) {
    const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
    // Optional: do something with response
}
```

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "ImageOps",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html",
        "default_title": "ImageOps"
    },
    "description": "Image scraper and modifier",
    "icons": {},
    "permissions": [
        "scripting",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to provide you with a concrete example. First of all, you need to modify your manifest.json to add a content script

manifest.json

```
   "content_scripts": [ // add this
      {
         "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
         ],
         "js": ["content.js"]
      }
   ],
```

Then, in your content.js file, you will write a message listener.

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( // this is the message listener
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === "autoFill")
            autoFill(request.textToFill);
    }
);

async function autoFill(textToFill){ // here write your function...
    console.log(textToFill)
}
```

You will now send a message from your popup.js.

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, 
        {
            message: "autoFill",
            textToFill: "some text" 
        }, function(response) {})
})
```

That's it!

If you need any more help or clarifications feel free to comment. Good luck with your project!