# React/Chrome extension - How to modify content of popup on URL change?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning Chrome extension development and want to update the content of my popup whenever theres change to the URL (Not a tab change!).

My content script is basically accessing the DOM and grabs some text to set as a name within Chrome localStorage. `popup.js` then retrieves the name from localStorage and outputs within the pop.up.

**Problem:** How can I re-run the content script whenever the current pages URL changes? I think I would need to use [chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onUpdated) but unsure of how to implement. How can I best implement this functionality?

So far I have the following:

**contentScript.js**

```
// Store name in localStorage
chrome.storage.local.set({ name });
```

**popup.js**

```
// Get name from localStorage and set as some state
useEffect(() => {
    chrome.storage.local.get('name', (data) => {
        setName(data.name);
    });
}, []);
```

manifest.json

```
"permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://site.storm.com/*"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
```

Comment: "chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener" that must be use in the "background.js" not in the contentScript.js file.

Comment: And check the MDN doc for an example code https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated#examples

Comment: You can use chrome.tabs.onUpdated in the popup or the background script as shown in tons of examples, then in its listener [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the tab's content script. It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @wOxxOm are you referring to `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`?

So I have included `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()` in my `popup.js`. I then included `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()` within the onUpdated listener.  

Now within my contentScript I have `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()` but  not receiving any messages. 

The concepts are not clicking yet but would appreciate further advice!

Comment: If you reload the extension, the content script won't run automatically. It runs only when the tab [re]loads, see [Chrome extension content script re-injection after upgrade or install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10994324)

Comment: I see, so I'm going to have to programmatically inject it