# "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist" when sending message from popup.js to content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I saw that questions regarding this error apeared a lot but i've tried all the suggested solutions, including disabling all of my other chrome extension, yet nothing fixed the bug.
I rememered to reload the extension after each time but the same error kept coming back.

I'll mention that my code does not include a "background.js" file since I didn't find any need in one, but I might be wrong to think I don't need it, I'm pretty new to this.

**my code:**

popup.js

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => 
{
  var activate_switch = document.querySelector("input[id=activate]");

   activate_switch.addEventListener('change', function()
   {
              if(this.checked) 
              {
                  console.log("activated");
                  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
                  {
                      if(tabs.length == 0)
                      { 
                          console.log("could not send mesage to current tab");
                      }
                      else
                      {
                      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message:"run"}, function(response)
                      {
                          console.log("Hello");
                      });
                      };  
                });
     }

          });
});
```

content.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if( request.message === "run" ) {
            console.log("made it");
        }
    }
);
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "First Chrome Extension",
"description": "Build an Extension!",
"version": "0.01",
"externally_connectable": {
    "ids": [
        "*"
    ]
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "background",
    "activeTab"
],
"action": {
    "default_title": "Scraper",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": [
            "contentScript.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
],
"manifest_version": 3
```

}

it raises an error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

Comment: If the active tab is a web page with an http/https URL, the likely reason is that you reloaded the extension without [reinjecting the content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10994324).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the callback function for chrome.tabs.sendMessage.

So instead of this:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message:"run"}, function(response)
{
    console.log("Hello");
});
```

Just do this:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message:"run"});
```