# Chrome extension service workers stops listening to events after opening popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm developing a chrome extension with MV3.

I've encountered an issue in which when I open the popup when clicking on the extension's icon the service worker background script stops receiving the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` events, even after I close the popup. The only way I can make it work again is by reloading the extension.

I will mention that the popup that I'm rendering is a react app, not sure if it has to do with the issue, but when I swap the popup content to a normal HTML with just a button or something it is working as expected

Basically what I'm trying to do in the extension is listen to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event to detect URL changes in the background script, and send a message to a content script in order to save some data to the chrome local storage.

**This is the manifest.json -**

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "Extension POC",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "activeTab"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "build\\index.html",
    "default_title": "Open Pane",
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**And this is the background.js -**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (!isPageDoneLoading(changeInfo)) {
        return;
    }
    const url = tab.url;
    const ticketId = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    if (isTargetURL(url) && !isNaN(ticketId)) {
        // Update the ID only if it doesn't equal to the previous one or if null
        if (!CURRENT_TICKET_ID || CURRENT_TICKET_ID !== ticketId) {
            CURRENT_TICKET_ID = ticketId;   
            
            const props = getProperties(ticketId);
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { action: {ticketId, props: props}  });
        }
    }
})
```

Any idea what may be the root cause or how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: ManifestV3 is still bugged in its very core: the registration of its service worker is extremely unreliable which already affects thousands of users for more than a year. Imagine the joy that awaits us when MV2 is disabled in ~3 months. You can observe the changes in the URL using a content script instead e.g. via the new `navigation` API.  Also note that if you reloaded the extension you also need to reload the tabs or [reinject he content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10994324).

Comment: @wOxxOm I see what you're saying. I have to say that I did quite some research and I did see a lot of bugs that has to do with the registration of the service worker like you said, but I did not see the specific case that I'm mentioning when its stops working after the popup is opened, this makes me wonder maybe I did something wrong.
BTW, my popup is rendering a react app, and when i swapped it to normal HTML with just a button everything seems to be working fine, so I guess it has to do with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What React version are you using? In the older React version, part of the `create-react-app` script creates a file called `serviceWorker.js`. and a call to it in `index.js`. When I created a new project with a newer React version, 18.X.X it didn't create this file. I suppose there is some conflict with the service worker of the chrome extension and the one react app created.

Comment: Seems to do the trick! thank you :)