# Chrome Extension - How to interact between the main extension popup (default_popup) and a page script (web_accessible_resources)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I created an extension, where I placed a script into a page markup and performs some actions according to the following [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/access-variables-and-functions-defined-in-page-context-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879):

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('code.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

I also displayed a checkbox in "default_popup" which should indicate whether to execute a part of methods in script from "code.js" *(web_accessible_resources)* or not.

However, I have no idea how to interact between the script from "content_scripts" *(which has access to "default_popup")* and the script from "web_accessible_resources".

Could you suggest something?

I understand that I can completely replace the "web_accessible_resources" script, but this does not seem to be the best practice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample of communication between popup and tab.

[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "content_scripts + popup",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.js

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
  console.log("Send");
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, "message", (response) => {
    console.log("Recv response = " + response.title);
    document.getElementById("title").innerText = response.title;
  });
});
```

matches.js

```js
console.log("matches.js");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log("Recv. Send response = " + document.title);
  sendResponse({ title: document.title });

  return true;
});
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      font-size: x-large;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="min-width:300px">
  <div id="title"></div><br>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but I'm assuming you have 3 things: (1) a pop up, (2) a content script, and (3) a script injected into the page, running in page context. Firstly, to send messages to the popup, you can run `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` and have a listener in your popup's script.js file with `chrome.runtime.onMessage()`. To get the data from the page script is different, it cannot communicate with your browser extension directly. So, from your page context script, you can create an element with a unique ID and store some data in an attribute. Use a modification of a MutationObserver to run a waitForElm() function (see this thread - [How to wait until an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists)). In your content script, you'll wait for the element to be created, collect data from the attribute you set, and then run `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` as mentioned earlier to get that data to your pop up.

Comment: Did I understand the question correctly?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

What I want to do is access the page's DOM from the Popup.

That is, I have a script embedded on my page and a popup with a checkbox. 
If I click on the checkbox, my script should get the value of the checkbox.