# How to use executeScript like a content script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am using execute script, but it only works when a user clicks on the icon. How can I make it so that it runs when the user moves to a new page like a content script?
I tried calling the function within the page but that also does not work.

```
const page = () => {
  alert("popup");
   
}

 function test(){

  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
    
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
      func: page
    });
  });
}


test()//does not work
```

Comment: "How can I make it so that it runs when the user moves to a new page like a content script?" -- Why don't you just use a content script? Please add this information to your question, because it will help us better understand it.

Comment: @ThomasMueller The code itself is located within a content script. Without execute script the code will only run within the popup window upon click. For example, the alert will only come from the icon window and not the user's webpage. Thats the reason for userScript

Comment: If you want people to help you, you need to give more information; a single code fragment is not enough. Edit the question so it contains the source code for the entire extension, one code block for each file (with the file name above it). Non-code files like `manifest.json` and HTML files should also be included. Then add a clear desription of what you want the extension to do. If you arent't willing to put this work into the question, I'm afraid it's unlikely you'll get an answer.

Comment: Hi @JohnThomas my guess is that you're unfamiliar with the concept of content scripts. The script that runs in the context of the popup is a background script. They behave differently and have different permissions. 
If you're unfamiliar with the chrome extension API, it would be helpful to either go study it a bit more, or add more files, references, and examples to your question.