# Chrome extenstion - error: Cannot access chrome:// URL (Manifest 3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

## Chrome Extension - Manifest V3

I am trying to build a simple chrome extension and am getting stuck on a particular error.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: **Cannot access a "chrome://" URL**

I found a way to counter the error, but it does not solve the problem itself.

I understood that when I use my extension, it works on "chrome://..." which I see when I inspect the extension, but can not figure out how to change that *(if that even needs changing)*

#### My code:

`manifest.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Super cool name",
    "description" : "A super cool intro",
    "author": "you wouldn't know him",

    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs"],
    "host_permissions": ["tabs", "notifications", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],

    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.mjs",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {...},
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {...},
    "content_scripts": [{
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["contentScripts.mjs"]
        }]
}
```

`background.mjs`

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, tab) => {
    if (tab.url?.startsWith("chrome://")) return undefined;

    if (tab.active && changeInfo.status === "complete") {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {tabId: tabId},
            files: ['contentScripts.mjs']
```

Any tips? Thank you for your time!

Comment: What does your extension do?

Comment: Simply remove your chrome.tabs.onUpdated because the browser already injects your `content_scripts` automatically. You'll still need to [re-inject the content script on update/install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10994324).