# Unable to persist state of my chrome extension between tab reloads and tab changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to create a pretty simple chrome extension that enables me to navigate the browser back and forward using horizontal scrolling. I want to be able to enable and disable the extension; however I want the state to persist when the tab changes (whether the active tab is a new url or a new tab is launched).

Here is my current code that partially works for **only** the active tab:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "SwipeNav",
  "action": {},
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Navigates browser forward and back with 2 finger swiping",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "tabs",
    "alarms"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```
function twoFingerBack() {
    console.log("Enabling 2 finger scrolling");
    
    let timer;

    window.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        if (Math.abs(event.deltaX) > Math.abs(event.deltaY)) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                if (event.deltaX > 0) {
                    history.back();
                } else if (event.deltaX < 0) {
                    history.forward();
                }
            }, 200);
        }
    });
}

function removeExt() {
    console.log("Disabling 2 finger scrolling");
    window.removeEventListener("wheel", removeExt)

}

let enabled = true;
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    enabled = !enabled;
    if (enabled) {
        if (!tab.url.includes("chrome://")) {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tab.id },
                function: twoFingerBack
            });
        }
    } else {
        if (!tab.url.includes("chrome://")) {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tab.id },
                function: removeExt
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I have read that I can use `chrome.tabs.onActivated` however I could not get this to work at all. Not sure if that is the right path.

Any help is appreciated...thanks!

Comment: Please use `localStorage` or `chrome.storage`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the state in storage. Since `localStorage` is not available in a service worker you can use [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/).
2. [Register/unregister](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-registerContentScripts) the content script, so it runs automatically next time the tab is loaded.
3. Process all tabs using executeScript to apply the changes to the currently loaded pages.
4. Use a global function for the wheel listener and use its name in `removeEventListener`.

// manifest.json

- Add `"storage"` inside `"permissions"`
- Add `"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]`

// background.js

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {
  let {enabled} = await chrome.storage.local.get('enabled');
  enabled = !enabled;
  chrome.storage.local.set({enabled});
  await chrome.scripting.unregisterContentScripts({ids: ['foo']}).catch(() => {});
  if (enabled) {
    chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts([{
      id: 'foo',
      js: ['content.js'],
      matches: ['<all_urls>'],
      runAt: 'document_start',
    }]);
  }
  const execOpts = enabled ? {files: ['content.js']} : {func: removeExt};
  const tabs = (await chrome.tabs.query({}))
    .sort(t => t.active ? -1 : 0); // processing the active tab(s) first
  for (const {id} of tabs) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: {tabId: id}, ...execOpts})
      .catch(() => {});
  }
});

function removeExt() {
  console.log('Disabling');
  // onWheel is the name of the global function used in content.js 
  if (typeof onWheel === 'function') removeEventListener('wheel', onWheel);
}
```

// content.js

```js
console.log('Enabling');
if (typeof onWheel !== 'function') (() => {
  let timer;
  window.onWheel = e => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    const x = e.deltaX;
    if (x && Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(e.deltaY)) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => x > 0 ? history.back() : history.forward(), 200);
    }
  };
  addEventListener('wheel', onWheel);
})();
```

Comment: As per the docs, [https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/] The action.onClicked event will not be dispatched if the extension action has specified a popup to show on click on the current tab.

Comment: I removed the default popup from manifest to try this code out but getting Nonexistent script ID 'foo'

Comment: 1) Your manifest.json is already correct so onClicked will be dispatched. 2) I've fixed the code.

Comment: This does not remove the eventlistner `onWheel` because it does not store the reference of that function that was added in content.js. Every time the `chrome.scripting.executeScript` executed, it creates a new reference. Also it gives an error `onWheel` not defined

Comment: Indeed, see the fixed code.

Comment: This content script is not loaded until you refresh the page when you use `chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts`. Is there any  other way?

Comment: Yes, see [Chrome extension content script re-injection after upgrade or install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10994324)