# Error reading local storage (Possibly Permission Issue)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my first time building a Google Chrome Extension, so I am still learning and possibly doing something silly.  Thank you for any help in advance.

Some background context:

Google Cloud Console IAM Admin page (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/) lists principles based on their project number.  For example, a principle may be listed as 123456789012-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com, where 123456789012 is a project id.  Obviously, 123456789012 isn't very human readable, so I wanted to build a chrome extension that would create tooltips over strings containing the project id where the tooltip text would be the project name.

I created a `background.js` script.  This script is used to toggle the chrome extension on / off.

```js
let extensionEnabled = false; // Variable to track extension state

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    extensionEnabled = !extensionEnabled; // Toggle extension state

    // Save the state of extensionEnabled to storage
    chrome.storage.local.set({ isEnabled: extensionEnabled });

    // Update the extension icon to indicate the current state
    const iconPath = extensionEnabled
        ? { '16': 'images/icon_enabled16.png', '48': 'images/icon_enabled48.png', '128': 'images/icon_enabled128.png' }
        : { '16': 'images/icon16.png', '48': 'images/icon48.png', '128': 'images/icon128.png' };
    chrome.action.setIcon({ path: iconPath });
});
```

I also created a `contentScript.js` file that contains the script logic.

```js
const wordMap = {
    // At present I am just hard-coding the project id number and project name
    "123456789012": "project-name",
};

let extensionEnabled = false;
// Load the state from storage
chrome.storage.local.get('isEnabled', (result) => {
    extensionEnabled = result.isEnabled || false;
    if (extensionEnabled) processPage();
});


function processPage() {
    // Create a new style element
    const style = document.createElement('style');

    // Set the CSS for tooltips
    style.textContent = `
...
`;

    // Append the style element to the head of the document
    document.head.appendChild(style);

    // Find occurrences of keys in wordMap in the text nodes of the document and put them in the textNodes array
    const textNodes = [];
    findTextNodes(document.body, textNodes);
    // This creates tooltips for all nodes in the textNodes array
    createTooltips(textNodes);
}
```

I've tested the logic on a test HTML document and `processPage()` works correctly on a simple static HTML document.

However, the extension wasn't working properly when using it in Google cloud console. The `textNodes` array was never being populated with any nodes. I suspect it's because in the Google console IAM page, they are populated / hydrated by the page's JS scripts.

Upon googling, I found some tips online that this is because the extension runs in an isolated environment. I tried changing the `world` key in my Manifest to `MAIN`. However this causes an error in the extension: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')` for the line `chrome.storage.local.get('isEnabled', (result)`

Here's my manifest file:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "GCP Project ID Tooltip Chrome Extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Chrome Extension that adds a tooltip with project names over project ID's in GCP console webpages.",
    "action": {},
    "permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "scripting"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://console.cloud.google.com/*"
      ],
      "optional_host_permissions":[
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
      ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "contentScript.js"
            ],
            "all_frames": true,
            "world": "MAIN"
        }
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon16.png",
        "48": "images/icon48.png",
        "128": "images/icon128.png"
    }
}
```

My few questions are:

- Do I need `"world": "MAIN"` set for my use case? or is `ISOLATED` good enough?

  - If I don't, I think that would resolve my `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')`, but then I am left with the `textNodes` array not being populated?
- What permissions do I need for my use-case?  I'm still unclear on the various permissions requirements for google chrome extensions.
- Do I need `host_permissions` or `optional_host_permissions`
- What should I put for `content_scripts.matches`? I suspect it's `https://console.cloud.google.com/`, but I want to confirm.
- Am I doing anything stupid here? Maybe there is a better/simpler way to accomplish this?

Thank you again for any insight!

Comment: Please read [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference) carefully.

Comment: The problem is caused by the fact that the page is created dynamically. You can use MutationObserver in the content script to detect the elements. Also use devtools with breakpoints to debug the code interactively and see the exact state of DOM at the time your code runs. There's no need for `world`, also switch to chrome.scripting instead of `content_scripts` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75283704).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for the tips! MutationObserver was very helpful. I was able to get things working using your suggestions. I still don't understand why use of `chrome.scripting` instead of `content_scripts` is needed in my scenario. According to the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/content-scripts#dynamic-declarative), it states "Dynamic content scripts are useful when the match patterns for content scripts are not well known or when content scripts should not always be injected on known hosts.". I don't think this applies in my case since I know this info?

Comment: When your extension is disabled your static content_scripts are still wastefully injected.

Answer (score 0):

Following the question comments, I was able to implement a solution using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).  I just followed the example in the docs, implementing it for my use case.  One note - if you're just learning - MutationObserver has to be in  your content script (not service worker background script).

Here's a part of my manifest file to answer the other questions I had:

```json
 "host_permissions": [
        "https://console.cloud.google.com/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "src/background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://console.cloud.google.com/*"
            ],
            "css": [
                "css/tooltip.css"
            ]
        }
    ],
```