Chrome Extension content script acting rly strange
So basically my removeFrame.js is acting really odd.
It's loaded from the manifest.json:
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["removeFrames.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],


this is my removeFrames.js:
    export {};
    
    function removeIframes() {
      document.querySelectorAll("iframe").forEach((iframe) => {
        iframe.parentNode?.removeChild(iframe);
      });
    }
    
    function observeMutations() {
      const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        removeIframes();
      });
    
      observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
      });
    }
    
    function initializeIframeRemoval() {
      chrome.storage.sync.get({ extensionState: "deactivated" }, (data) => {
        if (data.extensionState === "activated") {
          removeIframes(); // Remove existing iframes immediately
          observeMutations(); // Start observing for new iframe additions
        }
      });
    }
    
    initializeIframeRemoval();

And I normally set the if the extension is running or not from a button that triggers a case in my background script:
activation:
     // Set the extension state to 'activated'
      chrome.storage.sync.set({ extensionState: "activated" }, () => {
        console.log("Iframe removal activated");
      });

deactivation:
      // Set the extension state to 'deactivated'
      chrome.storage.sync.set({ extensionState: "deactivated" }, () => {
        console.log("Iframe removal deactivated");
      });

My problem is the next one:
After I activate it from the button if I reload the page with iframes is working properly it removes all the iframes on the page.
Now what's driving me crazy is that if I refresh the page a second time or enter it again by pressing back and clicking on the link again it doesn't do anything.
If I disable and re-enable from the button again, it's working again for the refresh, then stops working again.
Also if I open a new tab and access the page the script is working.
The page I'm trying to block the iframes on is
https://browserleaks.com/javascript
I have attached 2 pictures at the end.
If I change my removeFrames.js to this it will always work. But I need a method to disable and enable this content script ... I don't why is not working when I do that. I mean it works if I put a console.log in there i can see the console.log but the other functionality works only on top level, have no idea why. I mean at least when I refresh the page.
And now is more odd, if I refresh like 20 times or something like that the 21 time is working, sometimes if I refresh another 5 times it's working the 6th time ........
    export {};
    
    function removeIframes() {
      document.querySelectorAll("iframe").forEach((iframe) => {
        iframe.parentNode?.removeChild(iframe);
      });
    }
    
    function observeMutations() {
      const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        removeIframes();
      });
    
      observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
      });
    }
    removeIframes(); 
    observeMutations();

Here are 2 pictures:
1 load : 
Page refresh: 

Use chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts instead of content_scripts and chrome.storage.sync.get, example.

thanks for the suggestion but still the same problem, only works on first load of the page, anything else you I could try ?

I have a feeling that only top level functions are working in that file, I have no clue why, I mean the console.logs are working even if they are not top level, but other functionality in removeFrames.js is not working

Sounds like you navigate a modern SPA site that uses the same document and only fakes URL change. You can compare location.href to a previously saved global value inside MutationObserver.

I have modified the question and the scripts to make it easier to understand.

In that case you didn't implement my example correctly, maybe you didn't reload the extension after editing? I've just tried it on that site and it works.

maybe let me try the adaptation you posted. Thanks for taking the time

Instead of checking chrome.storage.sync.get inside the script that always runs, use chrome.scripting to toggle the script when the user toggles the option, so that your code runs synchronously and only when it's enabled.
Here's an adaptation of https://stackoverflow.com/a/75283704:
// manifest.json
  "action": {},
  "background": {"service_worker": "bg.js"},
  "host_permissions": ["https://browserleaks.com/"],
  "permissions": ["scripting", "storage"]

// content.js
self.mo = new MutationObserver(() => {
  const frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
  if (frames.length) {
    mo.disconnect();
    console.log('Removing %s iframes', frames.length);
    for (const f of [...frames]) f.remove();
    observe();
  }
});
self.observe = () => {
  mo.observe(document.documentElement, {childList: true, subtree: true});
};
if (document.head) // when running on demand, not at document_start
  for (const f of document.querySelectorAll('iframe'))
    f.remove();
observe();

// bg.js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(toggle);
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(toggle);

async function toggle(arg) {
  let {enabled} = await chrome.storage.local.get('enabled');
  enabled = enabled == null ? true : arg.reason ? enabled : !enabled;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({enabled});
  chrome.action.setTitle({title: enabled ? 'enabled' : ''});
  await chrome.scripting.unregisterContentScripts({ids: ['foo']}).catch(() => {});
  if (enabled) {
    chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts([{
      id: 'foo',
      js: ['content.js'],
      matches: ['<all_urls>'],
      runAt: 'document_start',
    }]);
  }
  const execOpts = enabled ? {files: ['content.js']} : {func: disableExt};
  const hosts = chrome.runtime.getManifest().host_permissions
    .map(h => h.endsWith('*') ? h : h + '*');
  const tabs = (await chrome.tabs.query({url: hosts}))
    .sort(t => t.active ? -1 : 0); // processing the active tab(s) first
  for (const {id} of tabs) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: {tabId: id}, ...execOpts})
      .catch(() => {});
  }
}

function disableExt() {
  self.mo?.disconnect?.();
  delete self.mo;
  delete self.observe;
}


it still doesn't work properly for me , maybe I'm too tiered today, I will try tomorrow, thanks for taking the time to adapt this.. I will try tomorrow when I'm fresh because today all I managed to do with this is when I was clicking somewhere on the webpage it removed the scripts, but I need them removed on page load, probably I missed something because I'm too tiered, thanks again

I've updated it to reregister after reloading the extension, not only on the first install.

it worked thanks a lot, I have to modify it a bit so I can move it to my button function, so I removed the toggle function and moved the functionality directly in my background.js "activateheaders" case. but yea thanks a lot, can you tell me why is working like this and not from the manifest.json thing ?

I don't know, probably because of the timing or storage bugs. It was the wrong approach anyway.

alright, again thanks a lot ! everything working perfectly now :)

This sound like a timing issue. The initializeScript() function might be running before the iframes you want to remove have been added to the page. This might explain why the script only removes iframes the first time you load the page, and why it sometimes works if you wait a few minutes before refreshing.
Try delaying the execution of initializeScript(): You could use something like setTimeout to delay the execution of initializeScript(), giving the page more time to load and add the iframes.
setTimeout(initializeScript, 3000); // Wait 3 seconds before running initializeScript

Re-run initializeScript() periodically. So instead of running it once when the page loads, run it every few seconds to catch any iframes that are added later.
setInterval(initializeScript, 3000); // Run initializeScript every 3 seconds

Use window.onload or document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {...}): These'll make sure your script is running after the entire page has loaded.
window.onload = initializeScript; // run initializeScript when window gets finished loading

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initializeScript); // Run initializeScript when the DOM is fully loaded

Hope this helps

Thanks for answering but that's not really the issue, I want to remove that initializeScript()  for good from the script itself. If you look at the removeFrame.js
//remove other iframes that observe mutations missed
it has a function that does just what you suggested and it's auto running, plus I need the iframes removed at document_start, not when the window finishes loading.
so initializeScript() is there commented just to test if it's working properly if I don't control it from a button.
