# css is not injected into the active tab in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to inject a css into my active tab
(https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/) programatically using jquery `.css()` function in my chrome extension , But the color change in the css is not reflected in the web page .

When the submit button in popup.js is clicked , it sends the color code to content.js , the content script which is supposed to then inject the css into the selected tags .

manifest.json :

```
{
    "manifest_version" :3 ,
    "name" : "PageFontstyle Extension" ,
    "version" :"1.0" ,
    "description" : "changes font style on a specific page" ,
    "icons" :{
        "128" :"icon128.jpg" ,
        "48" :"icon48.jpg" ,
        "16" :"icon16.jpg" 

    } ,
    "action" :{
        "default_icon" :"icon16.jpg" ,
        "default_popup" :"popup.html" ,
        "default_title" :"PageFontStyle" 
    },
    "background" :{
        "service_worker" : "eventPage.js" 
     
    } ,

    "content_scripts" :[{
        "matches" : ["https://developer.chrome.com/*"],
        "js" : ["content.js","jquery-3.7.0.min.js"]
        
    }
],

    "permissions" :[
        "tabs",
        "scripting",
        "activeTab"
    ]

    

}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PageFontStyle</title>
        <script src = "jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
        
        <script src="jscolor.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{
                min-width :250px ;
                min-height:150px ;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <form>
        
    <body>
        <input type = "text" id ="fontColor" data-jscolor="" />
        <input type = "submit" id="btnChange" value="change"/>
    </body>

    </form>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    
</html>
```

popup.js

```
$(function(){
    var color = $('#fontColor').val() ;
    $('#fontColor').on('change paste keyup',function(){
        color = $(this).val() ;
    }) ;

   
    $('#btnChange').click(function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({
            active: true,
            currentWindow: true
        }, async function(tabs) {
            await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                todo: "changeColor",
                clickedColor: color
            });
        });
    });

  

}) ;
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
    if (request.todo == "changeColor"){
        var addColor = "#" + request.clickedColor ;
        $('#view').css('color',addColor) ;      
    }
}) ;
```

Comment: What's in `eventPage.js` and `popup.html`?

Comment: On an unrelated note: "For unpacked extensions, images must be in the PNG format", see [chrome.browserAction > Icon](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/#icon)

Comment: See [Chrome extension content script re-injection after upgrade or install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10994324)